# Why are non-conservative tests desired over conservative ones?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

In my textbook, it says that P(Type I Error) =  α is a non-conservative test and my professor noted that this one is desired over the conservative test with P(Type I Error)  ≤ α. Why is that the case? Wouldn't we want the probability that we reject $H_0$ when it is true to be less than the significance level?

Edit: Conservative tests will detect a correct violation of the null hypothesis less often than a non-conservative tests (taken from the book).

Comment: Which textbook are you referencing?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your text is actually defining: $P(\text{Type 1 Error}) < \alpha (\text{nominal})$ as conservative and $P(\text{Type 1 Error}) \ge \alpha (\text{nominal})$ as non-conservative. So your definition in sentence two is not aligned with your edit: you should make the inequality in sentence two strict.

You might rather define $P(\text{Type 1 Error}) = \alpha (\text{nominal})$ as a test that is *well conserved* or *of the correct size* or *achieves nominal alpha level* or is *correct*. All these terms have been used from time to time.

There is no value in having a test that is anti-conservative.

Comment: Isn't a test "correct" or "valid" if $P(\text{Type 1 Error}) \geq \alpha$, according to the definition?

Comment: @dipetkov who's definition? Mine or OPs book? My take is that when comparing actual to nominal size of tests, <, =, and > are three distinct scenarios,

Comment: You have a point. Now I think a better question might be: are the "sometimes used" terms used consistently, that is to mean the same thing about the sign in $P(\text{type 1 error}) \text{ ?? } \alpha$. Maybe it's for the best to be explicit. PS: I know *level $\alpha$ test* to mean the type 1 error is at most $\alpha$.

Comment: @dipetkov I can't speak for the field on the whole, but I know I and my professors used these terms rigorously. For instance, despite its elegance, one can show Fisher's exact test is conservative, whereas Pearson's chi-square test "achieves the nominal 0.05 level" even when the sampling distribution of the test statistic is far from normal - barring pathological cases.

Answer (score 1):

When you set $\alpha$, you are saying that you accept a type I error rate of $\alpha$. Once you deem this acceptable, get as low of a type II error rate as you can!

Sure, you might be able to get a lower type I error rate, but that will sacrifice power, and you already decided that a type I error rate of $\alpha$ is acceptable.